# Datetime.now month is incorrect in c#

Tags: c#

I tried to display datetime.now using the code below

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("mm-dd-yyyy")
```

but it gives me a value like this. **35-08-2016**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The format `mm` stands for `minute`. Change it to

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: You were slightly faster than I...

Comment: If OP were testing this 40 minutes ago, it would have 'worked' fine ;)

Answer (score 4):

The correct value for month is "MM" not "mm"

mm -> minutes.

MM -> Month.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well no problem. Here's a +1 for you. :D I encounter that problem most of the time that's why I was quick to answer. :D

Comment: Have a look at the link... I find it safer to use the inbuilt template formats... That way you won't hit culture sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

The format is not correct, you should use `MM` with Uppercase letter. C# is a case sensitive. Using a different letter case will give you a different output.
here's a link to understand standard Date and Time.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

However, you can do a quick function so the date will using your culture like:

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(); //"01-08-2016"
DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(); //"Friday, January 08, 2016"
```